# Is methyl orange acidic or basic?

Tags: analytical-chemistry, ph

It has been saying that if adding too much indicator in solution, the ph value of solution would be changed. From this, it can be saying that indicators have a pH value. Methyl orange is the indicator I used in the experiment. "My question is whether methyl orange is basic or acidic so that it affects the pH value of solutions."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In an acidic solution, the protonation methyl orange takes place, as shown below

[image]

The deprotanted form depicted on the left is basic, and is yellow in colour. The red form is acidic and is depicted on the right.

In general, a lot of acid base-indicators rely on the following mechanism of action

$$\ce{In^-}+  \ce{<=>[\ce{H^+}][\ce{OH^-}]} \ce{HIn}$$

At low pH, i.e high $\ce{H^+}$ concentration the $\ce{HIn}$ form is dominant since the equilibrium lies to the right, however, at higher pH $\ce{HIn}$ (which is weakly acidic) dissasociates to give $\ce{In^-}$ (its conjugate base).

Herein, $\ce{HIn}$ (the acid), and $\ce{In^-}$ (its corresponding conjugate base) have different colours. The colour changes are due to changes in absorption, due to change in the length of the $\pi$ conjugated system (as can be seen in the case of methyl orange pictured above).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what form of it you have. The yellow form is basic, the red form is acidic.
This change is  done by the yellow one picking up a proton to form the red form.

[image: yellow form]   [image: red form]

In a solution which is getting less acidic, methyl orange will move from a red colour to orange and then at last to yellow with the reverse taking place for a solution increasing in acidity.
Therefore, in an acid, it is reddish and in alkali, it is yellow

<sub>Source:</sub>

- <sub>http://chemguide.co.uk/</sub>